# Neo4j nested query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with this cypher to retrieve nested data for a set of libraries, each having 0-X number of books with each book having 0-X number of authors.  The cypher looks like this:

```
MATCH (library:Library)--(book:Book)--(author:Author)
WITH library, book, {name: author.name} AS nest_author
WITH library, {name: book.name, authors: collect(nest_author)} AS nest_book
WITH {name: library.name, books: collect(nest_book)} AS nest_library
RETURN {library_data: collect(nest_library)}
```

The only problem with this cypher is that is only works when a library has a book and a book has an author.  I tried the query below, but the structure is lost and all the authors appear under all the books and all the books appear under all the libraries:

```
MATCH (library:Library),(book:Book),(author:Author)
OPTIONAL MATCH (library)--(book)
OPTIONAL MATCH (book)--(author)

WITH library, book, {name: author.name} AS nest_author
WITH library, {name: book.name, authors: collect(nest_author)} AS nest_book
WITH {name: library.name, books: collect(nest_book)} AS nest_library
RETURN {library_data: collect(nest_library)}
```

How would I write the first query so that the relationships are optional and the collect just returns an empty list when the library doesn't have any books or a book doesn't contain an author?

Answer (score 3):

In your second query you are creating *cross products* behavior.

Based on the following neo4j console example : http://console.neo4j.org/r/l1cpwz

This query do the trick :

```
MATCH (n:Library)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)--(book:Book)
OPTIONAL MATCH (book)--(author:Author)
RETURN n.name, collect({ book: book.title, author: author.lastname })
```

The example result is the following :

```
n.name  collect({ book: book.title, author: author.lastname })
aspernatur  [ {book:"Eligendi fuga est harum est nobis nam id.", author:null},  {book:"Numquam animi ex alias rerum quas.", author:null}]
consectetur [ {book:"Vel nostrum modi officia.", author:null},  {book:"Dolorum dolor optio aut ipsum.", author:null},  {book:"Iste sit quo reprehenderit dolores neque.", author:null}]
corrupti    [ {book:"Minus sit sed quia tempora quaerat.", author:null}]
deserunt    [ {book:"Temporibus impedit quod aut vel et.", author:null},  {book:"Praesentium perspiciatis blanditiis et omnis suscipit nostrum repudiandae.", author:null}]
labore  [ {book:"Non quis maxime doloremque et.", author:null},  {book:"Eos voluptatem voluptatibus mollitia exercitationem nobis.", author:null},  {book:"Vel voluptatem quae libero non est eaque.", author:null},  {book:"Atque velit accusantium perspiciatis assumenda voluptas ea corporis.", author:null}]
nihil   [ {book:"Deleniti illo earum eaque sapiente perspiciatis omnis quia.", author:null},  {book:"Est eum enim quo suscipit et molestias.", author:null},  {book:"Consequuntur nam temporibus explicabo quia ipsum.", author:null},  {book:"Facilis ratione illum ipsum sed cum ut.", author:null},  {book:"Est eos quis suscipit ratione alias necessitatibus asperiores sunt.", author:null},  {book:"Odit voluptatem est reiciendis quod tempora.", author:null}]
officiis    [ {book:"Ad libero porro quibusdam voluptatum.", author:null},  {book:"Numquam omnis ut unde sequi sint enim.", author:null}]
omnis   [ {book:"Qui laboriosam alias repellendus quibusdam incidunt et.", author:null},  {book:"Eos officia vitae consequatur qui.", author:null},  {book:"Explicabo nemo eos maxime.", author:null},  {book:"Dolores voluptatum et similique natus dolore fuga perferendis molestiae.", author:null},  {book:"Quidem aut ut ut quas veritatis.", author:null},  {book:"In in quos et aspernatur dolores.", author:null},  {book:"Alias sed quasi explicabo possimus veniam temporibus.", author:null},  {book:"Omnis dolor eum molestiae veritatis.", author:null}]
tempore [ {book:null, author:null}]
```